# Parsing a string to date and time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a string `"2011-05-19 10:30:14"` that I am trying to display as a date. I tried the following but it returns errors like "invalid date" and "arguments out of range" when I try:

```
"2011-05-19 10:30:14".to_date
```

And:

```
"2011-05-19 10:30:14".to_time
```

I also tried parsing with the DateTime class:

```
DateTime.parse("5-29-2013 10:17:04").
```

How do I get the date from this?

Comment: this might help http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse

Comment: If you are retrieving this data from a database and if the field is a sql date time field, then you will automatically get a Date object

Comment: What do you mean "display as a date"?  What is the form of your desired output?

Comment: thanks @SoylentGreen. I referred and got the answer!

Comment: @Aravind No problem! Just upvote me, accept my answer, AND vote for me in the upcoming elections for councilman! (I'm in your district) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting this as my answer because of the OP's comment...

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse

**EDIT**

Examples pulled from the link provided above:

```
DateTime.parse('2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00')
                      #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>
DateTime.parse('20010203T040506+0700')
                      #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>
DateTime.parse('3rd Feb 2001 04:05:06 PM')
                      #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T16:05:06+00:00 ...>
```

Comment: Please don't post just a link.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.strptime('2011-05-19 10:30:14', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This will give you a DateTime object and return:

```
 Thu, 19 May 2011 10:30:14 +0000
```

This will give you a DateTime object:

```
DateTime.strptime('2011-05-19 10:30:14', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').to_date
```

and return just the date:

```
Thu, 19 May 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `DateTime.strptime('2011-05-19 10:30:14', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Why should the OP try it? A single line answer needs an explanation to educate; Don't toss fish to people, teach them how to fish.

Comment: Take a look at some of my answers from just the last few hours. (About five hundred words of elaboration on fish and their habits, not counting code.) This one-liner is probably a bit terse, but getting into the ins-and-outs of `DateTime.strptime` was way more than OP needed.